# how does cordova add preferences to config.xml in the staging folder?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a cordova 4.3 project running in xcode with the iOS platform added.  In the config.xml file in the root of my project, I've added a preference `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>`.  However when I build or prepare the project quite a few preferences are added to the top of the config.xml file in the Staging directory, with the contents of my config.xml file appended at the bottom.  One of the preferences is `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>`, so the result is that it's first set to false and then set to true.

My main goal here is to figure out why the scrolling isn't turned off.  Is having both preferences inside config.xml causing a problem?  And if so how do I make it stop adding both preferences?

Comment: What version of cordova are you using?  It could be a bug. Check here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel

Did you try to trash your cordova project and start over?  Sometime funky things happen in cordova where the only viable solution is to trash the projtect and rebuild.  Just save the contents of your www and merges folder before trashing!

Comment: how do you build or prepare? from the CLI?

Comment: It's a bug, you should have opened it the first time you saw it. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9264

Comment: But I've been testing and the last one is the one that matters, when I put <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/> I can't scroll, so it's working as expected, consider updating the CLI and cordova version for the project